# Combine two integer indices and keep order

Tags: javascript, indexing

I have two integer-based indices, `index1` and `index2`. I want to combine them in such a way that the new index keeps the order of the originals, i.e.:

```
combineIndex(1, 2) > combineIndex(1, 1)
combineIndex(1, 3) > combineIndex(1, 2)
combineIndex(1, 4) > combineIndex(1, 3)
...
combineIndex(2, 1) > combineIndex(1, 100)
combineIndex(2, 2) > combineIndex(2, 1)
```

(the order of the first index > order of the second index)

I don't know the maximum value `index2` can take in advance and I want to keep the combined index as an integer (otherwise I could turn it into string via join/pad). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do something like that :

```
function combineIndices(index1, index2) {
    const combinedIndex = (index1 + index2) * (index1 + index2 + 1) / 2 + index2;
    return combinedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work: `combineIndices(2, 1)` is less than `combineIndices(1, 100)`